# Stating a universal ID in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following function for changing the CSS display on a given DIV

```
function(){

    if(document.getElementById('kitstory').style.display === "none")
        {
            document.getElementById('kitstory').style.display = "block";
        } else{
            document.getElementById('kitstory').style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

I'm using onclick in a link to call the function as and when required.

This works fine on my DIV with the ID "kitstory", but is there a way I can use this function for more than one DIV (I'll have several articles on 1 page with different DIV's I want the function to effect)? I've tried leaving the id blank but it doesn't run.

Comment: 'ID' is done for unique DOM elements, use 'class' instead and document.getElementsByClassName('kitstory') !

Comment: But would I be able to use that aspect on several items independently? ie. I have 3 news articles, I want to display the hidden text of just one, so you click the link. Would this approach not open up ALL items with class.kitstory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a named function and send the id as a parameter to the function:

```
function Toggle(id){
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  if (element.style.display === "none") {
    element.style.display = "block";
  } else{
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Toggle('kitstory');
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to work. I still need to define what the id is in the var element it seems

Comment: @wadey: No, you don't need a literal string for the id, a parameter works just fine. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/6NE3C/

Comment: Perfection!!! Worked a dream!! I did try this initially, but I left it blank instead of putting (id) and I didn't put the ' 'round the div when calling it.

Answer (score 1):

But of course! For example:

```
function toggleSingle(elementId) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if (el.style.display === 'none') {
    el.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

This function may be used by another function, which works with collections:

```
function toggleMultiple(elementIds) {
  if (! (elementIds && elementIds[0]) ) {
    // elementIds is not an array, should exit (and warn the developer as well perhaps)
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0, l = elementIds.length; i < l; ++i) {
    toggleSingle(elementIds[i]);
  }
}
```

Why did I write this as two functions and not one? Ok, that probably IS an overkill in this case, but in general I often separate the 'individual' item processing into a separate function: it makes my code more readable, and my tests more simple. Still, one can write an omnipotent function with something like this:

```
function toggleSmart() {
  for (var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; ++i) {
    var el = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
    if (el.style.display === 'none') {
      el.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
      el.style.display = 'none';
    }
    // and another way to do it: more concise, but less readable for some:
    // var display = el.style.display;
    // display = display === 'none' 
    //        ? 'block' 
    //        : 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think he's asking how to re-use code, rather how to apply it to more than one at a time. Still. It's a useful improvement to his approach.

Comment: Exactly Thor84no. If I have several div's which I want the function to apply to, but they all have different ID's.

Comment: @Thor84no Updated my answer to reflect this. In fact, I often tried to write my responses in more general way, so they can be helpful not only for one particular question - even though I often forget to mention that as well. )

Comment: Thanks @taina77ow. If I'm reading the 2nd function right, as long as I don't have the id's the same length, it should work? Am I reading that right (this is for my own learning more than anything)

Comment: @wadey No, the second function should take an array of elementIds as param, then walk over it with 'single toggling' function. So there is no restriction on id's length. )

Comment: So I would need to create an array with all my id's in first? Sorry if I'm being really slow and not understanding here

Comment: @wadey I'd say you should pass an array to it, it'll be something like this: `toggleMultiple(['div1', 'div2', 'div3'])`.

Comment: @raina77ow: `toggleSmart` could be a lot simpler if it used the built in `arguments` collection. You could iterate over that immediately. If no arguments are passed, the iteration will run 0 times, so you don't need to check that. If only one argument is passed, it will still be an array, of length 1, so no need to check that either. `function toggleSmart() { for(var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) { ... } }`. Invoked `toggleSmart('div1', 'div2', 'div3')` but `toggleSmart('div1')` would work as well.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Nice point, will update my answer. Usually I'm a bit cautious of iterating over `arguments` (because of JSDoc issues and some other reasons, too), but here it'll be quite in place.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of achieving this. The easiest ways I can think of are using `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsByClassName` and iterate over the list, or using a framework like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('some-class');

document.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

For instance:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('kitstory');
for(var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = (elements[i].style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

If class name or tag name do not immediately help you target the desired elements, you could also change `document` to something else:

```
var elements = document.getElementById('my-container').getElementsByTagName('div');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function yourAction() {
    if(this.style.display === "none") {
        ...
    }
}

var i, len;
for(i = 0, len = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); i < len; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].onclick = yourAction;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function change(id){

if(document.getElementById(id).style.display === "none")
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    } else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

then call function with change(divID);